# How to handle exceptions thrown in own ASP.NET user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, user-controls

I have created a user control that is using a library I have created. The library can throw a few exceptions, some which are of the kind that should not cause a run-time issue. I am unsure how to best proceed from this point in terms of handing those specific exceptions.

1. Do I include a label in my user control that will show a friendly
   message when the exceptions mentioned above are thrown?
2. Do I avoid catching the exceptions and let the user of the control decide what to do with them? Seems like this option would reveal information about the workings of the control.
3. Do I create my own exception(s) and throw those when catching any of the above mentioned exceptions?
4. Something else I have not thought about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't definitively handle them, then you shouldn't. Tidy up,as in catch, dispose throw is fine. It's "me" who wants to use the control, it's "me" who gets to decide what to do when an exception gets raised. All I can say is any suite of controls, that swallowed, hid or otherwise stuffed up a stacktrace in an error scenario, gets a 0/10, crap, don't buy it sticker from me.

Comment: I see what you are saying, and I believe I agree. I am curious about revealing that the control is using a certain class / library though. Is it something I should "worry" about?

Comment: I wouldn't but I'm an open sort of bloke. If you were thinking about obfuscation and hiding the how then raising your own good exceptions would be the way to go. You'd have to sell it to my boss though, me I'd be wondering what you were trying to hide. I'd buy a component suite to save my self the effort of writing one, not because I couldn't do it...